# Add a UIButton to ONE row of a UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I wanted to add a UIButton to just one row of a UITableView but I'm very confused.

When I use the following code, I get a button in row 2 at first but as I scroll up and down (I have 50 rows in the table) it seems to add more and more buttons until almost all rows have a button in.
What am I doing wrong :(

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell #%i", indexPath.row + 1];

if (indexPath.row == 2)
{
    //Create the button and add it to the cell
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(customActionPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Custom Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(150.0f, 5.0f, 150.0f, 30.0f);
    [cell addSubview:button];
}
return cell;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you could implement this by using two different identifiers for the cells.

Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *ButtonCellIdentifier = @"ButtonCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ButtonCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ButtonCellIdentifier] autorelease];
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [button addTarget:self 
                       action:@selector(customActionPressed:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [button setTitle:@"Custom Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(150.0f, 5.0f, 150.0f, 30.0f);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
            // in case you need the button later
            button.tag = 1024;
        }
        // in case you have to configure the button;
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1024];
        // configure button
    }
    else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell #%i", indexPath.row + 1];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: hi Matthias. That doesn't create any button...is there a mistake in the example?

Answer (score 0):

As you scroll, cells are reused as they go off the screen so the button needs to be removed.

What I would do is add the button to your cell in xib, and set it as hidden on all cells but the row you want.

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, set button to hidden at the start of your code before setting it visible on the row you want.
This way as rows are reused, the button is set to hidden